# How to make a Reminder notification?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How to make a Reminder notification?

For example, I have a reminder application and I want to get a notification on the event time (like as iPhone Calendar Notification).

Comment: Please stop editing your post title to add "with Swift". You already have set the Swift tag.

Comment: @EricD.  Sorry, I didn't know that.

Comment: No problem, Ghasem. That's why I left a comment, so you have the info now.

Comment: Please add what you have already tried and ask a specific question about what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this tutorial and you will learn how to send push notifications. In your case i think you only need to send local notifications, but its still quite complicated. You need to get some certificates to get provision for sending push notifications.

https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

Good luck!